# Can I have percentage width for child of div with white-space:nowrap

Tags: html, css

What green background to go fullwidth, if I change percentage width of item to px it works!

But I need it to be in percentage.

Should I have percentage width for childs inside parent overflow div, width of parent will also base on percentage.

```css
.frame {
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

.pane {
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: inline-block;
   background:green;
}

.item {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 18%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
   <div class="pane">
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div> 
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>            
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using viewport width and viewport height instead of percentages

check this snippet

```css
.frame {
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

.pane {
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: inline-block;
   background:green;
}

.item {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 18vw;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
   <div class="pane">
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div> 
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>            
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do here but unfortunately the CSS that you have is contradicting itself.

From what I can see you want a horizontally scrolling container, based on you having `overflow-x: scroll`.

You cannot use `white-space: nowrap;`, `display: inline-block;`, and `width: 18%;` all together. When an element is displayed inline or inline-block, its width is determined by its children, and elements with a percentage-based width get their width from the parent. You are essentially saying that the parent needs the children's width to determine its size, and that the children need the parent's width to determine their size. This does not make sense—you cannot solve for `x = y + z;` if you don't know what both `y` and `z` are. These properties are contradicting each other. What you want to do cannot be done with the properties you are trying to use.

To achieve what you want, you need to set the `.item` to have `display: block; float: left;` and the width to a fixed-unit size (e.g. pixels), and set the direct parent (`.pane`) width property to be the following equation:

```
width = (.item width + horizontal margins) * item count
```

So essentially, the width is the number of items you have multiplied by the calculated item width (which in the Codepen example provided, is 102px due to the horizontal margins), and then you multiply the item width by the number of items (so 10).

In my example I've included the pane width hardcoded in the CSS so you see what's happening, as well as the pane width calculated using jQuery (for the item with the class `.pane-calculated`). You can calculate this client-side as I did, or server-side and add the value as an inline style.

So assuming you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
   <div class="pane">
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div> 
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>
      <div class="item project-col"></div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

You would need the following CSS:

```
.frame {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 500px; /* this can be any width */
  border: 3px solid deeppink;
}

/* 
  pane width = item count * (item width + horizontal margins)
*/
.pane {
  width: 1020px; /* 102 * 10 */
}

.item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px; /* calculated width is 102px b/c of margin-right */
  margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

See the Codepen: http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/NbMaKJ?editors=1111

Comment: thanks a lot, Yes i need width be determined by childrens, px is not an option, js is not an option, seems like vw did the trick.